# Why isn't this switch block working?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm writing some code to calculate a certain valuation for a hierarchy (done in points). I'm using switch statements with a scanner (declared as a static variable), and for some reason in each of the boardTypes, the "y" and "n" cases don't break; they just go into the next boardType case. What am I doing wrong here?

```
System.out.println("Are they on board? (y/n)");
isOnBoard = s.nextLine();
switch (isOnBoard){
case "y":
    System.out.println("Chapter, regional, or international board? ");
    boardType = s.nextLine();
    switch (boardType){
    case "chapter":
        System.out.println("Are they chapter president? (y/n)");
        switch(s.nextLine()){
        case "y":
            totalPoints = chapterPres;
            break;
        case "n":
            totalPoints = chapterBoardMember;
            break;
        }
    case "regional":
        System.out.println("Are they regional president? (y/n)");
        switch(s.nextLine()){
        case "y":
            totalPoints = regionalPres;
            break;
        case "n":
            totalPoints = regionalExecutive;
            break;
        }
    case "international":
        System.out.println("Are they international president? (y/n)");
        switch(s.nextLine()){
        case "y":
            totalPoints = internationalPres;
            break;
        case "n":
            totalPoints = internationalExecutive;
            break;
        }
    case "n": break;
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lacking `break` statements - the fact that you enclose a block with `{ }` will not make it break:

```
case "chapter":
    System.out.println("Are they chapter president? (y/n)");
    switch(s.nextLine()){
    case "y":
        totalPoints = chapterPres;
        break;
    case "n":
        totalPoints = chapterBoardMember;
        break;
    }
    break; // This was missing
case "regional":
    System.out.println("Are they regional president? (y/n)");
    switch(s.nextLine()){
    case "y":
        totalPoints = regionalPres;
        break;
    case "n":
        totalPoints = regionalExecutive;
        break;
    }
    break; // This was missing
case "international":
    System.out.println("Are they international president? (y/n)");
    switch(s.nextLine()){
    case "y":
        totalPoints = internationalPres;
        break;
    case "n":
        totalPoints = internationalExecutive;
        break;
    }
    break; // This was missing
case "n": break;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I screwed up. Thank you so much... I'm still a beginner Java programmer :P

Answer (score 0):

You have `switch`s within `switch`s. The `break` statements break out of the inner one, but not the outer one. You need `break` in the outer ones, too:

```
switch (boardType){
    case "chapter":
        System.out.println("Are they chapter president? (y/n)");
        switch(s.nextLine()){
        case "y":
            totalPoints = chapterPres;
            break;  // <== Only breaks out of the inner `switch(s.nextLine())`
        case "n":
            totalPoints = chapterBoardMember;
            break;  // <== Only breaks out of the inner `switch(s.nextLine())`
        }
        break; // <=== Need this (and so on) to break out of outer switch
    case "regional":
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You break out from the inner case, not from the outer. You have to put a break to the outer case also.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can change your code with break statement for outer cases too   

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 System.out.println("Are they on board? (y/n)");
    isOnBoard = s.nextLine();
    switch (isOnBoard){
    case "y":
        System.out.println("Chapter, regional, or international board? ");
        boardType = s.nextLine();
        switch (boardType){
        case "chapter":
            System.out.println("Are they chapter president? (y/n)");
            switch(s.nextLine()){
            case "y":
                totalPoints = chapterPres;
                break;
            case "n":
                totalPoints = chapterBoardMember;
                break;
            }
    break;
        case "regional":
            System.out.println("Are they regional president? (y/n)");
            switch(s.nextLine()){
            case "y":
                totalPoints = regionalPres;
                break;
            case "n":
                totalPoints = regionalExecutive;
                break;
            }
    break;
        case "international":
            System.out.println("Are they international president? (y/n)");
            switch(s.nextLine()){
            case "y":
                totalPoints = internationalPres;
                break;
            case "n":
                totalPoints = internationalExecutive;
                break;
            }
    break;
        case "n": break;
    }
```